# ios - ASIHTTPREQUEST populating uitableview with json data

Tags: ios, uitableview, asihttprequest

I've been reading for hours and I can't figure out why my table won't reload itself with the updated data, here is the request I am making in block form:

```
 ASIHTTPRequest *_request= [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
__weak ASIHTTPRequest *request = _request;
request.requestMethod = @"POST";
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];


[request setDelegate:self];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);
    NSError* error;
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"request finished");
    [CommMTable reloadData];


}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

It gets the json object successfully as it  is printed in my console but the table doesn't update!

here is my table pragma section

```
(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.json count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    if(cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    cell.textLabel.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"title"];


    return cell;
}
```

any help is appreciated, this is really frustrating :(

Comment: you should use `NSNotificationCentre` and do reload your table. In this process Notification will notify your custom method that now it has data and go with reload table and then you will have data in your table View

Comment: I'll definitely try that out, I've seen some examples that are "supposed" to do what I want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I was doing everything correctly (json format and stuff were properly set).  The problem was that for some reason the table got disconnected from it's delegate and datasource, for the people who had a similar problem try this solution.

In the xib file just ctrl + drag the tableview to the File Owner and connect it to the delegate and datasource.

or you can do it with just code if you don't like the interface builder with the following lines

```
[myTableView setDataSource:self];
[myTableView setDelegate:self];
```

or

```
self.tableView.delegate = self.tableDelegate;
self.tableView.datasource = self.tableDelegate;
```

both either/or should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether json array has been updated or not? And you have used json array as property(self.json) in pragma sections not in inside blocks.

Comment: json is an array declared in my .h file and I synthesized it in the .m file.

Answer (score 0):

`json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];`

On doing this, the json array will be available only in the scope of `setCompletionBlock`.

Since you have synthesized json array, you need to assign it like

`self.json  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];`

If this was also not worked, just check whether the format of json was correct and you are parsing  the json properly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.